# Suppose A is a countable subset of an uncountable set B. Show that B - A is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uncountable minus countable set is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189649/uncountable-minus-countable-set-is-uncountable)

Proposition:

Suppose A is a countable subset of an uncountable set B. Show that B - A is uncountable.

Please help.

Comment: Hint: Prove that the union of two countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $B-A$ is countable. Now we find that the union of $B-A$ and $A$ which is $B$ is countable (contradiction)