# Generalized version of uncountable minus countable is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I think my question is generalized version of [Uncountable minus countable set is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189649/uncountable-minus-countable-set-is-uncountable)

I have to show: if $A$ is an infinite set, and $B$ is a subset of $A$, which satisfies $|B|<|A|$, then $|A-B|=|A|$.

I understood the answer to the link above. My textbook advised me to use Axiom of Choice, but I don't know how to apply it into this theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the axiom of choice implies that summing two cardinals, for infinite cardinals, is the same as taking the $\max$.

Now recall that $|A|=|A-B|+|B|$.