# Prove Uncountable minus countable set is uncountable based on cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if A is an uncountable set and B is a countable set, then A∖B must be uncountable.

I understand I am asking the same question as [Uncountable minus countable set is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189649/uncountable-minus-countable-set-is-uncountable)
but I am trying a different approach that I have not seen in the answers. Is this still a valid proof or am I missing something.

Let ${S\subset{U}}$ and $S$ and $U$ are countable and uncountable respectively. Then we have $|S|$ = $|\mathbb{N}|$ and $|U| > |\mathbb{N}|$.

Let's assume $|U-S|$ is countable so $|U-S| = |\mathbb{N}|$.

$$|U-S| = |U| - |S|$$
$$|\mathbb{N}| = |U| - |\mathbb{N}|$$
$$|2\mathbb{N}| = |U|$$
$$|\mathbb{N}| = |U|$$

This is a contradiction because U is uncountable. So we have that $|U-S|$ is uncountable.

Comment: I find it hard to distinguish this from the first answer to [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189649/uncountable-minus-countable-set-is-uncountable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that $\vert X-Y\vert=\vert X\vert-\vert Y\vert$. In fact, the right hand side doesn't even make sense: we can't subtract cardinals in any good way, since addition of cardinals isn't cancellative *(since $$\aleph_0+0=\aleph_0+17=\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0,$$ should $\aleph_0-\aleph_0$ be $0$, $17$, $\aleph_0$, or something else?)*.

Instead, we have to reason purely additively: we **do** always have $$\vert X\vert +\vert Y\vert=\vert X\cup Y\vert$$ for disjoint $X,Y$ *(and if either $X$ or $Y$ is infinite we don't need disjointness)*. Now take $X=B$ and $Y=A\setminus B$. If both $X$ and $Y$ were countable we would have $$\vert A\vert =\vert X\cup Y\vert=\vert X\vert +\vert Y\vert=\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0,$$ contradicting the uncountability of $A$; so if we take a countable set away from an uncountable set, we can't be left with an uncountable set.

Comment: For $|X|+|Y| = |X\cup Y|$ to avoid confusion with the finite cases, shouldn't it read $|X|+|Y|=|X\sqcup Y|$ implying trivial intersection or have the hypothesis that at least one of $X,Y$ be infinite?

Comment: @JMoravitz Agh, I keep forgetting finite sets exist. Fixing ...

Comment: Just curious can we say $|U-S| = |U| + |S|$ for sets? I know this is true for numbers.

Comment: @Sirlethian I don't think you wrote what you intended ... But regardless, I suspect not: in general the *disjoint* and *non-disjoint* cases will yield different values for the left hand side, so you won't get any good equalities in general.

Comment: Oh that's right! I forgot that U-S means the set that contains all elements of U not in S.