# can $(\mathbb{R},t)$ be connected?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

**Question 1**

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the real numbers with the topology  $t=\{A\subseteq \mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R}\setminus A= \text{finite} \}\cup \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R} \}$, can  $(\mathbb{R},t)$ be connected ?

I think it is connected since a connected topological space has only $\emptyset, X$ both open and closed. If we assume that $U \in t$ then $U^c \notin t$  because if it did then that would mean that $U$ is finite, $U=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ the compliment $\mathbb{R}\setminus U =\text{finite } \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}=\text{finite }$  which cant be true, hence the only open and closed sets are  $\emptyset,\mathbb{R}  $

**Question 2**

> $f:X \rightarrow Y$ continuous and onto then if $X$ is compact $Y$ is compact

since $f$ is onto $f(X)=Y$, and also for every $V_i \in X$ we can write it as $f^{-1}(U_i)=V_i$ where  $U_i \in Y$ and its open  , $i\in \mathbb{N}$

because $X$ is compact $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}V_i,  V_i= $ open

$\Rightarrow f(X)=f(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}V_i) \Rightarrow Y=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}f(V_i) =\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}U_i $

the reason I am asking for a verification is because I find them quite easy and i want to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: One question per post, please. You have two unrelated questions here. Make them two separate posts. By the way you misspelled "complement".

Comment: Are you saying a compact subset can be expressed as a finite union of open sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remarks on **Question 1** are correct. In general, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathcal{N}$ is infinite, where $\mathcal{N}$ is a countable set ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189649/uncountable-minus-countable-set-is-uncountable)).

For **Question 2** You have the right idea, but I would rephrase it as follows:

Let $\mathcal{C}=\{C_i\in \mathcal{T}_Y:i\in I\}$ be an open cover of $Y$, where $I$ is some indexing set, and $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is the topology on $Y$. Then $$Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}C_i\Longrightarrow X=f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}C_i\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f^{-1}(C_i)$$
I presume you can finish it from here by using continuity and surjectivity of $f$.

Note that I say some indexing set $I$ because using $\mathbb{N}$ as an indexing set for your open covers only accounts for countable covers, where you need to also account for uncountable open covers.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for Q1 is correct but the one for Q2 is wrong. To prove that $Y$ is compact you have to start with an open conver of $Y$. If $(V_i)$ is such a cover then $(f^{-1]}(V_i))$ is an open cover of $X$, so it has   finite subcover. Now you can complete as you did before. [Only the starting point of your proof is wrong].